# Overloading the function operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

One of the problems with loggers is that they log even when you don't want them to. They're usually either hardwired to write to a file or echo to the console - sometimes both.
This runs contrary to unit testing where logging to either sink will slow the tests down.

I am also against using printf style variadic arguments as they will be invariably wrong due to people cutting, pasting and forgetting to change the parameter type or to remove a parameter from the string.

So I decided to do something about it.

My basic idea would be to have a LogStream object that accepts an `ostream` as a parameter so you can specify a file, the console or silently swallow it during unit tests. This is passed
as a parameter to a Logger class that also accepts a severity level.

This is the conceptual flow for a logger that only logs fatal events to an ostringstream (paraphrased from a unit test):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
auto logstream = LogStream(oss);
auto logger = Logger(logstream, FATAL);
logger(INFO) << "This is a log test\n"; // (1)
std::cout << oss.str();  // Display nothing as nothing fatal has been logged
```

Thinking about the problem, I will need a temporary stream (ostream would work) to hold the stream before deciding whether it satisfies the criteria to be placed in the LogStream object.

The problem I am having is on line(1) you will have the function call operator which returns the reference to the LogStream and after it has exited the rest of the stream is constructed:

```
LogStream& operator()(Severity severity)
{
    // stream not completed
    return *m_dest;
}
```

I think there is a way since you can get friend functions that overload the insertion operator which take a stream parameter:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Complex& c)
{
    os << c.real << '.' << c.imaginary;
    return os;
}
```

But as of yet I have been unable to figure out the exact syntax for the function operator.

Is it possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Reinveting the wheel seldom yields rewards. There is no shortage of logging facilities which meet your requirement. Boost.Log and Log4cpp to name a few.

Comment: Normally I would agree but pulling in libraries that are orders of magnitude larger than your project seems a bit OTT (and I know that only the headers are pulled in or you just linking a static library).

Comment: Your syntax for the function operator is correct (as a member function). What's your question?

Comment: OTOH, reinventing the wheel is fine? *sigh*.

Comment: @graham.reeds *Normally I would agree but pulling in libraries that are orders of magnitude larger than your project* -- And in many cases, by the time you work out all the bugs, corner cases, etc.  your home-made library would come close to the size of the other libraries.

Comment: `Poco` provides logging facilities as well. If your project is large enough to require sophisticated logging, it will probably benefit from the various other features core libraries like Boost or Poco provide as well.

Comment: @Karoly It's not fine, but I just wanted something more in depth than littering the code with cout but not as full featured as boost or log4.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Currently it is 3 classes and I can't imagine it being more than 200 lines of code if I can figure out how to get the completed stream passed to the function operator. I had thought of macros but I hate them as they hide code and bugs.

Comment: @Sebastian It's hardly sophisticated logging. Never used Poco and never been on my radar but I am less likely to use it than boost which I have used in the past.

Comment: Ignore the haters, there's nothing wrong with wanting to know how to do your own thing even if there's already a library to do it. But I agree with @ecatmur, what's the actual question? http://ideone.com/21ODyX

Comment: @MarkRansom &ecatmur (Sorry I thought I had responded to this yesterday after responding to the others). I am trying to figure out a way of using the completed temporary stream in the function call operator.  My current way doesn't work (the stream is not created until the return occurs) so I am try to look for other ways of performing it.  My desired syntax is nice but I am unsure if it is actually possible.

Comment: But the example code you have doesn't create a temporary stream! You'll have to do a better job of explaining what you need.

Comment: @MarkRansom It doesn't have a temporary stream because I realised as I wrote the signature that it wouldn't work as I intended and I need to come up with an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

You need sth like this design:

```
enum class LogLevel
{
    FATAL,
    INFO
};

class LogStream : public std::ostream
{
public:
    LogStream( const std::ostream& )
    // ...
    {
    }

};

class EatStream : public std::ostream
{
    // does nothing 
};

class Logger
{
    const LogStream m_logger;
    const EatStream m_nolog;
    const LogLevel  m_loglevel;
public:
    Logger( const LogStream&&, const LogLevel ) // I'd suggest move, but you might as well just take a reference and copy
    // ...
    {
        // ...
    }

    std::ostream& operator()( const LogLevel level )
    {
        return  level <= m_loglevel ? m_logger : m_nolog;
    }
};
```

The key here is that LogStream and EatStream have a common base and your operator() returns *by reference*. It does not have to be std::ostream, that's just used because of convenience or lazines. As soon as you return a reference to the common base, you can call virtuals from vftable correctly. Note that the reference you return is kept alive by Logger, so it should not go out of scope earlier than the result of operator()() (this is probably not an issue in your case, just noted for completeness).

Comment: While I can see this certainly would work - I hadn't thought of using a null stream.  However I had left something out of the original post that wouldn't be possible with your solution. Once I had the initial version working I planned to change it so it could accept an array of LogStreams so you could have debug written to a text file, informational echoed to the screen, and all written to another file.

Comment: You certainly can do this, just create a LogMultipleStream that inherits from the common base and has a vector of LogStreams and operator<<(); then store this in Logger instead of LogStream.

Comment: But how do you return twice from the function call operator? This is why I was trying to work out if there was a way of getting the completed stream.

Comment: Also wouldn't the `m_nolog` stream get constantly larger as more things were ignored?